References for mean curvature in low-regularity settings.
Suppose you have a smooth manifold $(M,g)$ with metric tensor $g$ which is Lipschitz (Riemannian or Lorentzian). Given any hypersurface $\Sigma\subset M$, the connection coefficients may not be defined at all on $\Sigma$ since the latter is $\mathrm{vol}_g$-negligible and the connection coefficients are $L^\infty$.
Is there any reference on how to define a notion of mean curvature for $\Sigma$ in this context of low-regularity metric tensor? I know about the definition given by C. Ketterer in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06146 (Definition 5.7) or the mean curvature bounds (in the Lorentzian context) given by F. Cavalletti and A. Mondino in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.08934 (definition 5.2), which are synthetic definitions of mean curvature (bounds) equivalent to the smooth counterparts via basically the exponential map which one does not have if $g$ is Lipschitz.
Any suggestion and/or reference would be very much appreciated!
